# Rescale pixel's size pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm using pygame 1.9.
How to make window bigger, than it's size definite by pixel's size.
For example, I create display with 100x100 pixel.
And fill it by numpy array.

```
screenarray=np.zeros((100, 100))
screenarray.fill(10)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(screenarray)
screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

And it's too small, I even can see anything.
I want to rescale it by 600x600 pixels of my display.
How to rescale "pixel's size"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really get what you were trying to explain but maybe newSurface = pygame.transform.scale(surface, (newWidth, newHeight)) is the right thing for you.

Comment: I want to create window(200x200) but my input data is numpy array is only 100x100

Comment: Do newSurface = pygame.transform.scale(surface,(newWidth,newHeight))

Comment: @WYCE Kindly move the comments to the answer by using the [edit] option.