# Pygame: Rescale pixel size

Tags: python, pygame

With pygame, I created a 20x20 pixel window and added a 2x2 pixel rectangle.
When I run the program, the window size is super small and I can barely see the rectangle. How can I increase the window size whilst keeping the number of pixels constant, i.e. increase the pixel size? I am aware of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778994/rescale-pixels-size-pygame), but there a somewhat more complicated case is discussed.

```
import pygame
screen_width, screen_height = 20, 20
x, y = 10, 10
rect_width, rect_height = 2, 2
vel = 2
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    win.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (x, y, rect_width, rect_height))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Why not just increase the size of the window and rectangle?

Comment: It is due to my special use case: I want to train a neural network on a game and the input layer has a limited neuron number, namely 400.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't draw directly to the screen, but to another `Surface`.

Then scale that new `Surface` to the size of the screen and blit it onto the real screen surface.

Here's an example:

```
import pygame
screen_width, screen_height = 20, 20

scaling_factor = 6

x, y = 10, 10
rect_width, rect_height = 2, 2
vel = 2
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width*scaling_factor, screen_height*scaling_factor))

screen = pygame.Surface((screen_width, screen_height))

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x, y, rect_width, rect_height))

    win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(screen, win.get_rect().size), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```